# Angular is changing query string parameter

Tags: angularjs

We are using DPS's PXPay to generate payments for our app.

On a successful transaction the url that is provided looks like

http://ourapp.com/checkout/complete?result=v5eX-DlMlfGe2FUcPeZgCFiKhZwgmCVhlTfL-rtnPszpe8S_6MYJMbVPDK14h7KxQM6xfKYUnXhz_RcSOHqw4VwHX97GU9XINHwh9DFt6aDHOLMvdAnSwZost5H2aOQlZgMESDzlwNGx_lfgeLba2Us41x437J3PWTJ_LLJVK4OY_7K4c6rxQ88Mve7FfoYd7P8CAZWxyHbC-wxCyLiocw4_NQ_34ct-IAsR1MM3C2OkPijfBAk-l72rOOMWGp8EoLpdOHyT0uITvsdjMvOFIHIMnSdVs2JFCslAmTRMDl4jkb5ezBf9wKZuo91KgII0kd9dFJMFCm7evt-X0ykLw_vjcgg85kZoRbDvi89nEGiWmFLVKM_xVgZYufeMMudOGRcHgi4i-RZJ4mml2JMzN2OtJKyQdpxuC-3b9KfnRbyy_F75Gak5fwJIf4tvo6VNJKUJuBtKYKafPyH_YJU4HQMeHP8uO0-FhMN3mzRCmGjvExuqx1BhA67R35pmaTbyxz-06JEvIqzf8FTftoBowLSeu37KtNmagZ8cJpMlCe4kUaFY4v6ZTx7h9rYx37oYtZNsSR1t3KDFzQYRs5LAg8RQ==&userid=OurDevId

This is definitely the request that is coming into the browser. BUT what is displayed in my browser URL bar... and what angular reads for the "result" token is this...

http://ourapp.com/checkout/complete?result=v5eX-DlMlfGe2FUcPeZgCFiKhZwgmCVhlTfL-rtnPszpe8S_6MYJMbVPDK14h7KxQM6xfKYUnXhz_RcSOHqw4VwHX97GU9XINHwh9DFt6aDHOLMvdAnSwZost5H2aOQlZgMESDzlwNGx_lfgeLba2Us41x437J3PWTJ_LLJVK4OY_7K4c6rxQ88Mve7FfoYd7P8CAZWxyHbC-wxCyLiocw4_NQ_34ct-IAsR1MM3C2OkPijfBAk-l72rOOMWGp8EoLpdOHyT0uITvsdjMvOFIHIMnSdVs2JFCslAmTRMDl4jkb5ezBf9wKZuo91KgII0kd9dFJMFCm7evt-X0ykLw_vjcgg85kZoRbDvi89nEGiWmFLVKM_xVgZYufeMMudOGRcHgi4i-RZJ4mml2JMzN2OtJKyQdpxuC-3b9KfnRbyy_F75Gak5fwJIf4tvo6VNJKUJuBtKYKafPyH_YJU4HQMeHP8uO0-FhMN3mzRCmGjvExuqx1BhA67R35pmaTbyxz-06JEvIqzf8FTftoBowLSeu37KtNmagZ8cJpMlCe4kUaFY4v6ZTx7h9rYx37oYtZNsSR1t3KDFzQYRs5LAg8RQ&userid=OurDevId

If you look closely... the two '==' are being taken off the end of the "result" token string.

I've tested in non angular applications and this isn't happening. Why does angular do this and how do I prevent it?

Comment: might be $sce `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce`

Comment: Might also get away with some manual setting of $location properties. I've used a service before to hold the actual string and then set $location.path and $location.url to equal it.

Comment: the problem is the "=="'s are being stripped out of the url before they get to $location service. It must be some kind of sanitization going on behind the scenes. Trying to work out how I read the request before angular gets to it

Answer (score 0):

Angular cannot handle `==` because of its `$location`'s `search` parsing. Just visit : https://angularjs.org/?foo==123 and the url will change to https://angularjs.org/?foo=

The same will not happen on a non-angular page.

Solution: Either patch angular OR HTML encode the section after `?result=`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've guessed this is the case by now. Can you point me in the direction of how I would HTML encode the section after ?result ??.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do with the URL that is returned, it might be simpler to just set `window.location` directly instead of working through Angular. This bypasses the query-string parsing in `$location` that's stripping the double equals.

Comment: What I've ended up doing is storing the token in the query string as 'document.resultToken' before angular is initiated. Then I can access it in my angular controller. Feels very dirty but it's working

Comment: Working is better than broken. Ping me on AirPair when you're ready to clean it up.